# does git reset delete history?

Tags: git, security, github

I accidentally commited something that might be sensetive information in git (only locally) and I wanna remove it from git history in a simple way. Will

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

and then unstage the sensetive information and add to gitignore be enough to completely remove it from git history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a soft reset is not enough.
Doing this will leave the file in your index (where you stage files to be committed). This means, that git is still tracking the file.

You will want to do a mixed reset, which unstages these files as well. As René pointed out, it is also a good idea to remove the file or add it to your `.gitignore` so you don't accidentally commit it again.

This is enough so the sensitive information will not be transmitted to a remote server on `git push`.

However, the information is still in your local repository. If you ever "loose" a commit by accidentally resetting too far, [git reflog](http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits) is a very useful tool.

Now to clean all away all commits, that are not reachable through a branch or tag:

```
git reflog expire --expire=1.minute --all
git prune
git gc
```

1. Removes all entries older than 1 minute from the reflog. A commit will not be removed, if there is any remaining reference to it. Such a reference can come from another commit, a branch, a tag and also the reflog.
2. Removes all commits that aren't reachable anymore.
3. Does a number of housekeeping tasks. For more info look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

`reflog expire` and `prune` are destructive operations. I recommend running these commands with the `--dry-run` argument first, to see what exactly gets removed.

Answer (score 4):

`git reset --soft HEAD~1` resets only the `HEAD` to the previous commit while the index and working directory is not touched.

This means that the index and working directory still reflects the state that contains the sensitive information. Just remove these files from the index `git reset HEAD <file>...` and commit again.

After you removed the sensitive data files from the index, they will remain in the working directory. Maybe you also want to delete them from the working directory or add them to `.gitignore`.

**EDIT**

> Do you mean I should first do git reset --soft HEAD~1 and then git reset HEAD ?

Yes. Normally you stage files `git add ..` and then commit them. If you do a `git reset --soft HEAD~1` your repository reflects the state just before that commit. You can see this if you do a `git status`. So you can modify the index and commit again.

> Also, does this remove the data 100% from git history?

No, not completely. If a commit is not referenced anymore git will delete it after 90 days (default value - see [`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)). If you want to delete it immediately, you must ensure that it is not referenced anymore. Therefore you must delete it from any reflog that contains it, e.g. `git reflog --delete HEAD@{3}`. Normally it will be contained in the reflog of the `HEAD` and your branch. Also ensure that it is not contained in any branch, e.g. if the commit if is `A` do a `git branch -a --contains A`. The output must be empty.

Then you can garbage collect it using `git gc --prune=now`. Check that the commit has been deleted using `git log -n1 COMMIT-ID`. It should output `fatal: bad object`.

For details on removing files and direcotries from git take a look at my blog https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2014/07/17/remove-directories-and-files-permanently-from-git/.

Comment: Do you mean I should first do git reset --soft HEAD~1 and then git reset HEAD <file>? Also, does this remove the data 100% from git history? Just wanna make sure.

Answer (score 2):

No need for `--soft`: `git reset HEAD~1` will unstage the current commit files by resetting the index in addition of moving HEAD.

Then a `.gitignore` will be enough to ignore that file.

> Do you mean I should first do `git reset --soft HEAD~1` and then `git reset HEAD <file>`?

No, you need to remove the all commit to be sure the history won't include your sensitive file.

```
git reset HEAD~1
echo sensitiveFile >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git add -A .
git commit -m "Redo commit, without sensitiveFile"
```

Comment: Why isn't my example sufficent? git reset HEAD <file> removes the file from history, doesn't it? Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Mattias `git reset HEAD -- <file>` only reset a file, but doesn't change the current commit (which still include your sensitive file). You would be able to make a new commit without your file, but the history (previous commit) would still reference the sensitive file. To really remove it from the history, you need to redo the previous commit, not just the file.

Comment: If I do `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, which will reset to the previous commit (the one before the sensetive file was commited), and then do `git reset HEAD -- <file>`, which will remove the sensetive file from the git index, won't I get the exact same result as by doing `git reset HEAD~1` except that I keep all non-sensetive files in index?

Comment: There is no need for `git reset HEAD -- <file>`: you just reset to the previous commit, and redo your commit, but this time with a .gitignore which will prevent your sensitive file to be included in said re-done commit. That is *not* equivalent  of `git reset HEAD -- <file>`, which will prepare a new commit without the file (but the previous one still has it)

Comment: You're forgetting `git reset --soft HEAD~1` before... I'm saying if I do `git reset --soft HEAD~1` BEFORE `git reset HEAD -- <file>`. These 2 commands TOGETHER will delete the commit with the sensitive file FIRST, THEN remove the file from being commited again, will they not? Sorry if I'm being annoying, I'd just like to set this straight.

Comment: @Mattias nope: you just need `git reset --soft HEAD~1`: it will reset the all index, for the all commit, and that includes resetting the file. No need for "2 commands together". The idea is to undo the commit, and redo it (with this time the file ignored in a `.gitignore` file)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87821/discussion-between-mattias-and-vonc).